# Invoking a spring web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws

I'm trying to invoke a spring web service, using below url in browser the service "myservice" should return XML, ie based on the @RequestMapping annotations is the below URL correct?

```
> http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/myservice/feeds/allFeeds.xml/


import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("myservice")
public class TheController {

    private TheService TheServiceWS;

    public TheController(TheService TheServiceWS) {
        this.TheServiceWS = TheServiceWS;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "feeds/allFeeds.xml", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getValues() {
        return TheServiceWS.getAllFeeds();
    }

}
```

Comment: This depends on where you deploy your application. Also, just a guess, try `allFeeds.xml` instead of `allFeeds.xml/`

Comment: how is your web.xml configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was :

The @RequestMapping annotation value "myservice" was incorrect

should have been "mywebservice"

Answer (score 0):

If the web service return as XML, it is the original the SOAP web service. In this case, you couldn't build the web service with @RequestMapping. The @RequestMapping is used when you want to build a REST web service.

In this case, you should use the Spring WS. You have to annotate the class with @Endpoint to create an web service endpoint. In the this endpoint, you create your request mapping with @Payloadroot. Please refer to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)